# in django why isn't my slug being automatically generated when I create a post

Tags: django-forms

I have a form thats connected to my model. I was tring to save it but I was getting an error letting me know that the slug field wasn't being satisfied. So to my form I added slug and created a slug manually from my title and it worked. I already have this in my admin.py

```
 prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

so why is this not happening automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after reviewing other code I had to do this

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
```

then do this

```
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

then the slug was generated without me having to add it manually or slugifying it in the view